# Laravel 4: Routing based on URI

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, uri, laravel-routing

Folks,

I am trying to do something simple. If for example in my Settings navigation looks like this:

```
http://localhost/settings/   
http://localhost/settings/general
http://localhost/settings/message
http://localhost/settings/users
```

Is this possible in any way to make my router know that when it sees settings/users, I want it to go to SettingsController@users? and settings/general to go to SettingsController@general

Thing is, I dont want to have to put down each url in the routes.php like:

```
Route::any("settings/users", array("as" => "users", "uses" => "SettingsController@users"));
Route::any("settings/general", array("as" => "general", "uses" => "SettingsController@general"));
```

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Route Controller in your routes.php like

```
Route::controller('settings', 'SettingsController');
```

and in your SettingsController define at the below methods.

```
class SettingsController extends BaseController {

    //URL : http://localhost/settings
    public function getIndex()
    {
        echo 'Index Method';

    }

    //URL : http://localhost/settings/message
    public function getMessage()
    {
        echo 'Message Method';
    }
}
```

You have to use 'get' prefix and start with Upper character. For more information please check http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Comment: Thanks Muharrem! Working perfectly now.

Comment: Hi @Muharrem, I met with a challenge after using this method. Using the same concept as in your above solution, when I'm sending ajax request to my controller, I get a 404 error. But when i enter that url in my browser, it works. For example, I send ajax request to http://localhost/abc/settings/user_status. Where user_status is a method in Settings controller. This gives a 404 error using ajax but works when put directly in browser.  Considering that this Settings controller has other methods that are not called by ajax, how do I write my route and controller? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi @Tochie. I think the reason is your ajax request type. If the problem is that , there is two solution you can try to change ajax type(Change header or jquery method type) with 'GET' or you can change route Controller prefix with post like:  function postMessage().. otherwise pls send me your ajax code.